# How to count code lines automaticly in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse plugin for measuring lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986744/eclipse-plugin-for-measuring-lines-of-code)

I really don't want to manually go through each class in my java project. I have BILLIONS of classes and I really want to know how many lines I created. Is there a way to know automatically the lines of code on all classes?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, we are happy to answer specific technical questions. But please have the curtesy of using the search function and Serch Engines before asking!

Comment: Install the Eclipse Metrics Plugin. To create a HTML report (with optional XML and CSV) right-click a project -> Export -> Other -> Metrics.

You can adjust the Lines of Code metrics by ignoring blank and comment-only lines or exclude Javadoc if you want. To do this check the tab at Preferences -> Metrics -> LoC.

That's it. There is no special option to exclude curly braces {}.

The plugin offers an alternative metric to LoC called Number of Statements. This is what the author has to say about it:

Answer (score 0):

I use this code analyze tool: https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-codepro

it tells the lines of code and more